# How much focus should be given to Siphoning Strike while clearing camps on Jungle Nasus

Tags: league-of-legends

As a Nasus jungler, I can't decide what is more important.

Should I not use E for the weaker camps and try Q-last-hit even the small monsters or should I just Q-last-hit what I can (usually the biggest monster), but always use E and smite?

To clarify, I'm asking what solution is better in the long run in terms of making me generally stronger in team fights under normal circumstances.

Comment: The way the question is worded right now may solicit mostly opinion-based answers, which we try to avoid on Arqade. Is there a way that you could reword it to make the "best" solution more quantifiable? (i.e. asking which is more efficient in terms of gold/XP gain, or whatever other metric you care about the most)

Comment: Okay I've edited my question a little. But I am asking this question this generally in case there is a strategically obvious answer even though the question may seem to be an opinion asking question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Q to last-hit as much as possible, but not at the expense of speed (much, a second or two is probably ok). The faster you clear the jungle, the more experience you've earned, and the more gold, which leads to potency faster than Q-stacking alone.

Additionally, you'll be able to assist your allies more, possibly picking up Q-stacks from lane minions and enemy champions, as well as forcing/protecting turrets and dragons.

Comment: I don't know if its worth noting, but as nasus jungle, early game you're gank usefulness comes from whither and spirit fire, siphon strike is just a bonus. Q farm is nice and all, but higher level(faster farm) is definitely more important